# Mikrotik Integration with ERP-LIKE systems?

Tags: mikrotik

I'm looking to integrate a mikrotik server in my ERP-LIKE application, but I have no idea to start such a thing.

What do I need to know about mikritik to do such integration?
In my system actually I do my own IP ranges, Register of all my servers, Customers, Accouting, Technical Data about my customers include speed of navigation and a lot of other stuffs usefull to an ISP company.

Actually everything is done direct in the mikritik server, but I wish to do the inverse way, everything need to be done in the System Module Mikrotik in my personal ERP-Like System.

In short I need that Mikritik read the configuration that come from the system, to do this I can use cron-jobs (no problem), but how can Mikritik read such an external file?

p.s.: My system was built with php programming language.

Thanks for any help on this matter.

The Best Wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using the API, if you are using PHP language then it helps -> http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_PHP_class